# Compiled modules support for openWRT

Tags: wifi, kernel-modules, openwrt, route, router

In order to add driver for my wireless adapter,

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter`

I am building openWRT for my GL.iNet AR150. The source I use is 
[gl-inet/openWRT](https://github.com/gl-inet/openwrt)

According to [this page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/rtl819x), my card RTL8191SU should be supported by the driver rtl8192su. However,  after I chose rtl8192su in `make menuconfig` and building the whole openWRT, I cannot find the module in `/lib/modules`. Even more confusing is that, under `/lib/modules/` there are two folders, `3.18.84` and `4.9.102`, while the kernel I'm running is `4.9.102`.

Using `find` I can locate the pkg of rtl8192su but not the ko files. As a sanity check, I also looked at another driver I selected in menuconfig, rtl8187, which is found but in the `/lib/modules/3.18.84` folder instead of `4.9.102` folder. Did I miss something obvious?

Thanks.

Update: 
Now the adapter can be recognized.

```
[  545.455019] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform
[  545.651473] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[  545.655903] usb 1-1: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[  545.675639] usb 1-1: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[  546.508983] usb 1-1: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x000a
[  546.512163] usb 1-1: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 08:10:79:56:a8:90
[  546.518852] usb 1-1: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
```

but I am having trouble to connect it to a known network. After `ifconfig wlan1 up` I can see it's running. However, when I connect it using `iwconfig wlan1 essid "_networkID_" key s:_password_` no IP is assigned. Is there anything I can try with to find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You should assign an address ip to your interface and set up the default gatway:

```
iwconfig wlan1 essid "networkID" key s:password
```

or:

```
iwconfig wlan1 essid "networkID" key password
```

Then:

```
ifconfig wlan1 192.168.1.xxx netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```